# Unable to access codable struct values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, codable

I am fetching user's data as json from a service and decoding into Codable User struct. I can access that property where I've fetched the response but I want to access that User struct property somewhere else, let's say in another class, function, etc.

I'm new to this and I'm thinking the ideal approach is to "at the time of fetching, store that data into `Core Data` or `User Defaults` and then update my views accordingly.

Please suggest what's the best and appropriate approach or wether there is any way to access codable struct values directly.

**Here is my codable struct -**

```
struct User: Codable {
let name : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "Name"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
  }
}
```

The wrong way I'm accessing struct in some function is -

```
UserInfo.CodingKeys.name.rawValue
//Output is the key string - 'Name'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be accusing it using something like more like `someReferenceToUser.name`?

Comment: *"but I want to access that User struct property somewhere else, let's say in another class, function, etc"* so the reference to `User` needs to be available to those classes/functions.  Either you need to pass it to those elements or make it globally available in some way ... although, I'd look at how you would do this by passing the reference.  You might consider Realm, but that might be to heavy weight for what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

I think `static` can help you

```
struct User: Codable {
 let name : String?

 private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case name = "Name"
 }
}
```

assume fetching data here

```
class FetchingClass{
  static var user: User?

 func fetchData(){
  //After Url request success
  do {
  //assign directly to static varibale user
  FetchingClass.user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
} catch _ {
   }
  }
}
```

use like this wherever you want without using `coreData` or `UserDefaults`

```
class AnotherClass{
 func anotherClassFunc(){
 //use if let or guard let
  if let user = FetchingClass.user{
  print(user.name)
 }
 //or
 if let FetchingClass.user != nil {
  print(FetchingClass.name)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a singleton reference

```
struct User: Codable {

    let name : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        User.shared = self
    }
}
```

---

Create another class which hold the ref. of `User`

```
final class AppGlobalManager  {
       static let sharedInstance = AppGlobalManager()

       var currentUser: User? // Initialise it when user logged in   

       private init()

}
```

Then you can access any of the user data as

```
AppGlobalManager.sharedInstance.currentUser.name
```

Comment: Why are you creating shared instance ? as it can be directly accessed  with refe.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya with singleton you don't need to pass the reference and as its static you can access it anywhere in the app.

Comment: Yes but you should create separate class with shared instance , which has user ref object. with that you don't need to create Codable class shared instance inside the class Hope you get my point

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya That is totally a personal choice and also depends on what architecture you are using for the app. I like to keep my model classes minimum so I only create pure model classes for my parsers and protocols for my view classes

Comment: You are correct that is personal choice. but for me it seems to be bad practice to have shared instance inside the codable class and may be hard to manage in future update or when the size of project is increased. but if we can keep all at one place that can be easy to manage.

Comment: @nishithSingh I'm a fan of singletons and used it in my node projects but just realized not to use them, after reading this article - https://cocoacasts.com/are-singletons-bad/  Also, I have no idea about Dependency Injections. Any clue what's the right approach?

Comment: And if I have to use a singleton, why would I create a new one but not use User Defaults as it's itself a singleton? Just curious!